# Refactor query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that needs to check the value from object list if it exists by loop through the value of the main object. How can recode below?

```
foreach (var kd in dto.KeyDriverModels)
{
  var keyDriverModelNodeValue = result.SingleOrDefault(x => x.KeyDriverModelId == kd.ID);
  kd.SelectionStatus = keyDriverModelNodeValue != null ? 
                         keyDriverModelNodeValue.SelectionStatus : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *recode*?

Comment: Why would you do this? Isn't it working? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: That's not a query, you're changing values on your `KeyDriverModel` objects. You don't need more LINQ...

Comment: The code is working, I am just getting your idea if there are some approach other than the way I code it.

Comment: @JeffMercado- What do you think the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to model your code and rewrite the code as Linq.  See if this works

```css
        static DTO dto = new DTO();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<KeyDriver> keyDrivers = new List<KeyDriver>();
            List<KeyDriver> result = keyDrivers.Where(x => x.KeyDriverModelId > 1000).ToList();

            foreach (var kd in dto.KeyDriverModels)
            {
                var keyDriverModelNodeValue = result.SingleOrDefault(x => x.KeyDriverModelId == kd.ID);
                kd.SelectionStatus = keyDriverModelNodeValue != null ?
                                       keyDriverModelNodeValue.SelectionStatus : string.Empty;
            }

            //new code
            var kd1 = from r in result
                      join d in dto.KeyDriverModels
                      on r.KeyDriverModelId equals d.ID  into drs
                      from dr in drs
                      select new { dr }.dr.SelectionStatus != null ? dr.SelectionStatus : string.Empty;
        }
    }
    public class DTO
    {
        public List<KeyDriverModel> KeyDriverModels { get; set; }
    }
    public class KeyDriverModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SelectionStatus { get; set; }
    }
    public class KeyDriver
    {
        public int KeyDriverModelId { get; set; }
        public string SelectionStatus { get; set; }

    }
​
```